# javascript find nested objects in another array and do math

Tags: javascript, pug

I need to find the two nested objects from 'products.accessories' array in 'accessories' array and   check their currency to multiply with parity, check their unit to multiply with 'products.properties.length', multiply each with their 'qty' and sum their result.

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

```
var accessories = [{
  name: 'Accessory-1',
  currency: 'eur',
  price: 1,
  unit: 'm'
},
{
  name: 'Accessory-2',
  currency: 'usd',
  price: 2,
  unit: 'pcs'
}];

var products = [{
  name: 'Product',
  properties: [{
    no: 'Product-1',
    length: '2000',
    accessories: [{
      name: 'Accessory-1',
      qty: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Accessory-2',
      qty: 1
    }]
  }]
}];
```

```
// currencies
let eurusd = 1.18
let gbpusd = 1.38
```

### EDIT: Thank you, @AlexeyZelenin

```
    function getPrice(accessory) {
        accessory.unit === 'm' ? unitMultiplier = length / 1000 : unitMultiplier = 1
        return (
            accessory.currency === 'eur' ? (accessory.price * eurusd) : 
                (accessory.currency === 'gbp' ? (accessory.price * gbpusd) : 
                        accessory.price)
                        ).toFixed(2)
    }
```

```
    function getAcc(property) { 
        return property.accessories 
            .map(x => x.qty * getPrice(accessories.find(p => p.name === x.name)) * unitMultiplier)
            .reduce((c, p) => c + p)
    }
```

**PUG:**

```
each i in products
     .....
     each j in i.properties
          .....
          length = j.length
          .....
```

Comment: Where is "product.currency" field?

Comment: @AlexeyZelenin product has no currency, it is USD, I only need to convert the accessory price to USD same with product.

Comment: your function `getPrice()` declares, that there should be `price` and `currency` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Accessories: each accessory might be presented several times with different currencies
var accessories = [
  {
      name: 'Accessory-1',
      currency: 'eur',
      price: 3,
      unit: 'm',
  },
  {
      name: 'Accessory-2',
      currency: 'eur',
      price: 5,
      unit: 'm',
  },
  {
      name: 'Accessory-3',
      currency: 'usd',
      price: 2,
      unit: 'pcs',
  },  
]

// Products - each product has properties with "accessories" inside
var products = [
  {
      name: 'Product',
      properties:
      [
          {
              no: 'Product-1',
              length: '2000',
              accessories: [
                      {
                      name: 'Accessory-1', 
                      qty: 2
                      },
                      {
                      name: 'Accessory-2', 
                      qty: 2
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'Accessory-3', 
                        qty: 1
                        },
                    ]
          },
      ]
  }
];

//currencies
let eurusd = 1.18;
let gbpusd = 1.38;
//functions
function getPrice(product) {
  return (
      product.currency === 'eur' ? (product.price * eurusd) : 
          (product.currency === 'gbp' ? (product.price * gbpusd)     : 
              product.price)).toFixed(2);
}

// The function gets one product as an incoming parameter
// Then gets the list of all accessories for all properties
// Finds the accessory from the global array, calculates right price
// based on accessory currency and multiplies it by accessory quantity
// Then summarises all prices
function getAccessories(product) {
  return product.properties
    .map(x => ({
      accessories: x.accessories.map(b => ({
        ...b, 
        length: +x.length
      }))
    }))
    .flatMap(x => x.accessories) // get all accessories
    .map(x => x.length * x.qty * getPrice(accessories.find(p => p.name === x.name))) // find the price of accessory from global array
    .reduce((c, p) => c + p) // sum prices
    ;
}
console.log(getAccessories(products[0]));
```

Comment: I don't need currency in products. I am already calculating their price based on USD, but the accessory currencies are variable, so I only need to multiply parities with accessory prices unless they are USD.

Comment: Ok. Let's try it another way. We expect, that every accessory is presented in the global array just once and we need to calculate the real price using the coefficient.

Comment: thats actualy what I need, I understand the logic now I have to integrate the * product.length according to its unit. Thank you very much!

Comment: btw this sums accessory prices from every property nested to product, however I need to calculate each property price individually caused by flatMap()

Comment: I split the query on 3 parts for a reason - so you can easier adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Added the length multiplication. It might be different for different properties, so we can't use the constant value

Comment: I took a longer route but get to what I need at the end thanks to you.

Comment: You might want to mark the answer as a good one :-)